# Running R Through a .NET program

Tags: c#, r

I have a program that is written in C#. It runs Rscript.exe within threads. The R files read from big `dat` files and after doing equations on them, they write the output to excel files.

Here is the problem:

When I run the R file through R Studio it creates excel files. But when I run my program it randomly writes the output or it does not.

Maybe the thread closes before R stream flushes. How can i diagnose it ? What else maybe the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

With working on our exception handling we saw that we we're running 32 Bit program instead of 64 and it was running out of memory at half of operation. We used the 64 bit and it solved the problem.